# How to catch cellmouseclicks in dynamically created datagridviews on TabPages

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

```
Sub Tabs()
     Dim shtWork1 As Short
     Dim dbpath As String = "db\... "
     Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(dbpath ... )

     For shtWork1 = 1 To shtMaxTabs

        Dim TabPageAll As New TabPage
        Try
            'define DataGridViews                 
            Dim DataGridView1 As New DataGridView

            DataGridView1.Parent = TabPageAll
            .
            .
            .
            DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True

            TabControl1.TabPages.Add(TabPageAll)

        Catch ex as ...  
            Message
        Finally
            Close()
        End Try
    Next shtWork1
End Sub
```

' The Grids are created on the TabPages and work fine.
 But if I click on a cell it should give me the possibility to execute some other code i.e.
 filling textboxes on that specific TabPage.
Any idea would be apreciated.
TIA Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an event handler when adding your DataGridView

```
AddHandler DataGridView1.CellClick, AddressOf cellClickHandler
```

This is an example handler code

```
Private Sub cellClickHandler(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Row '{0}', Col '{1}'", e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex))
End Sub
```

**Edit:**

Complete solution

Add a tab control to a new winforms app. Just add this code to Form1 class.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim tabPageAll As New TabPage()
    Dim dataGridView1 As New DataGridView()
    Dim d As New Dictionary(Of String, String)() _
        From {{"A", "1"}, {"B", "2"}, {"C", "3"}}
    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
    dataGridView1.DataSource = _
        (From ds In d
         Select New With {.Key = ds.Key, .Value = ds.Value}).ToArray()
    AddHandler dataGridView1.CellClick, AddressOf cellClickHandler
    tabPageAll.Controls.Add(dataGridView1)
    TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPageAll)
    TabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPageAll
End Sub

Private Sub cellClickHandler(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex >= 0 Then
        ' DataGridView.Rows() works just fine here
        Dim selectedRow = CType(sender, DataGridView).Rows(e.RowIndex)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Clicking will be catched now. But there's a new issue

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseClick
        Dim TestFlag As Integer
        Dim strRefNumber As String = ""
        If e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex >= 0 Then

            Dim selectedRow = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex) DataGridView1.Rows gives a 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' 
The value of DataGridView1.Rows is 0 ...

Comment: Looks like there are 0 rows. Does that happen after you populate the datagridview with data?

Comment: DataGridViews are all populatet. as soon as i click on the first cell of the DGV on the first TabPage the programm jumps to the sub cellmouseclick. there e.RowIndex and e.ColumnIndex have value but .Rows of System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection gives the exception! TIA

Comment: I just tried out the example in your first comment. The event handler signature looks wrong - you have `ByVal e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs` where it should be `DataGridViewCellEventArgs`.

Comment: I am rewriting my solution to show a complete solution with minimal code to demonstrate the idea works. It works on my end at least. Let me know

Comment: You are fantastic. I only put the Dim selectedRow = Ctype... into the clickHandler sub -> no error and I get all the fields of the clicked Row in the Sub. But what have I to do to put the fieldcontent i.e. in a listbox on the TabPage from where I clicked?It seems that I have no relation to the TabPage...

Comment: But what have I to do to put the fieldcontent i.e. in a listbox on the TabPage from where I clicked?It seems that I have no relation to the TabPage...